# link_tag() not working in codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeIgniter, and I created one simple module.
In my code I have created a home controller and the Home.php follows

```
 public function index() {
    $data['title'] = 'Welcome';
    $this->load->view('home/index', $data);
 }
```

I created one view file in view/home/index.php  with the following code

```
link_tag('css/style.css');
echo $title;
```

When I use link_tag(), it shows the following error message

Fatal error: Call to undefined function link_tag() in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\application\views\home\index.php on line 2

Kindly help me from this issue.

Answer (score 4):

You first need to load this helper: `$this->load->helper('html');`

For the `link_tag()` to work, you need to load the HTML helper like this `$this->load->helper('html');`

so in your controller code, I would add it like this:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $data['title'] = 'Welcome';
    $this->load->view('home/index', $data);
 }
```

Comment: could you please explain. so that i can try. Where i can put this code.?

Answer (score 2):

For adding **`$this->load->helper('html')`** in each function we can use **`$autoload['helper'] = array('html');`** in `application/config/autoload.php` file

Answer (score 0):

For using `link_tag()` you need to load `html helper`

You can load it using

```
$this->load->helper('html');
```

Then your code look like this

```
public function index() {
$this->load->helper('html');
$data['title'] = 'Welcome';
$this->load->view('home/index', $data);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You first need to load this helper:

```
$this->load->helper('html');
```

or autoload the HTML helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('html');
```

Then your code looks like this

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->helper('html');// don't need if you autoload the html helper
    $data['title'] = 'Welcome';
    $this->load->view('home/index', $data);
 }
```